# Configure Local Resource Windows Azure

Tags: c#, azure

I have a question regarding [Local Storage Resource](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-local-storage-resources/)

It has a property called `cleanOnRoleRecycle`, if I set it to false data is supposed to persist even if the role recycles (or I assume restarted manually)

```
<LocalStorage name="localStoreTwo" sizeInMB="10" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" />
```

Local resource generally points to a dynamically generated path %user%\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources**528b6963-b931-43c9-87ba-53f1d69c5954**

> When my cloud service comes up after role recycle. Will my persisted
>   storage data be still accessible by cloud service?

**EDIT:**
I will rephrase my question: Everytime a role is recyled/restarted LocalStorage directory is a new GUID, so even if the data persisted in old directory, Azure service may not pick it up! Because it does not know which was the old GUID path. In that case `cleanOnRoleRecycle="false"` may be just for reviewing data not for actual use.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-local-storage-resources/):

> You can specify that a local storage resource be preserved when an
>   instance is recycled. **However, data that is saved to the local file
>   system of the virtual machine is not guaranteed to be durable.**

If it is really important data, I don't think you should base your logic on the assumption that data stored in local storage will be available to you always because you set `cleanOnRoleRecycle` to `false`. Also think about the scenario where your existing VM is replaced with another VM for whatever reason.

**UPDATE**

So I did some more research and found out that the GUID you mentioned is same as deployment id. So as long as your deployment id does not change (which would be the case in role recycles or reboots), your local storage directory will not change.

Comment: These are lucene search indexes & not a critical data

Comment: But my question is pertaining to everytime a role is recyled/restarted LocalStorage directory is a new GUID, so even if the data persists Azure service may not pick it up! Because it does not know which was the old GUID path.

Comment: Updated my answer. HTH.